# Como Crear una Vista de Editar en AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Como podria hacer que al darle click en el Boton Editar, poder abrir un formulario donde lleno todos los datos para editar la empresa que sale en la tabla??.
En la consulta muestro solo 6 Datos Basicos pero en realidad son mas y quisiera mostrarlos en una ventana y asi editarlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco colaboracion, soy muy nuevo en esto de angularJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día. Estoy suponiendo estás usando routing y programando una SPA, así que me basaré en esto para darte una respuesta.

En tu botón editar debes indicar que se cambie de vista, por ejemplo:

```
<button ng-click="edit(company)">Editar</button>
```

En tu controlador defines la función edit:

```
$scope.edit = (company) => {
  $location.path(`editar/${company._id}`);
};
```

Esto lo que hará es cambiar tu path a algo así: `/editar/n4503nc`. Se supone debes tener dicha URL mapeada en el router:

```
$routeProvider
  ...
  .when('/empresas/editar/:id', {
      template: 'editar-empresa.html',
      controller: 'EditCompanyCtrl'
  });
```

El `EditCompanyCtrl` recibirá el parámetro `id` que contiene el ID de la compañía a editar. En el controlador lo que debes hacer es hacer una petición al backend vía AJAX y obtener los datos de la compañía con dicho ID. Una vez obtenidos, solo lo agregas al `$scope`.

```
app.controller('EditCompanyCtrl', ($scope, $routeParams) => {
  $.get(`/api/companies/${routeParams.id}`)
    .then((company) => {
      $scope.company = company;
    });
});
```

---

Para una modal, no hay mayor misterio. Solo ten la modal bajo el mando del mismo controlador.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tan excelente explicacion, soy nuevo en esto pero te he entendido muy bien! Mis rutas no son asi /empresas/editar/:id', pero ya miro como la creo de esa manera. Creo que el modal ya no lo necesito, con tu ejemplo lo haria con una pagina nueva. Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: De nada amigo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

si lo quieres hacer con un modal, me imagino que adicionas con un modal también... porque la idea es reutilizar el ng-model.
por ejemplo:

`<div class"modal fade" id="modal"> <form>... <buttom type="submit" ng-show="create"></buttom> Crear</div>
<buttom type="submit" ng-show="!create">Actualizar</buttom> </form></div>`

en la controller tienes por supuesto que definir una variable "create" que se pone en true o false dependiendo de si estas creando o actualizando.
por ejemplo:

`$('form').submit(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
if (!$scope.create){
actualizar();
}else{
crear();
}
}`